Minimum molar mass of organic compound with given mass fraction of carbon
Problem from my coaching module:

An organic compound X contains 10% C by mass. The minimum molar mass of compound X is (in g/mol)

100
120
150
200


I think the compound must have an integer amount of carbon atoms. Since 10% of 120 g/mol is 12 g/mol and matches the molar mass of carbon, the answer appears to be 120 g/mol. Is it really this simple, or am I missing something?

Your understanding is correct.

Is there any real organic compounds that can have $10$% C by mass with a molar mass $120$ ? $\ce{Li2CS3}$ has a molar weight $14 + 12 + 96 = 122$. But is it an organic compound ?

I can think of a very simple chlorofluoro compound that is close to this ratio. So sounds reasonable.

Yes, you are correct: the number of carbon atoms should be the unity. Further, to prevent any disputes about the organic nature of the compound, a carbon–hydrogen bond would be nice to have.
Monoisotopic chloroform with $M_\mathrm{mi}(\ce{^{12}C^1H^{35}Cl2^{37}Cl}) = \pu{120 Da}$ has exactly (well, omitting mass defect) $10~\%$ carbon-12 by mass. Even for the averaged $M(\ce{CHCl3}) = \pu{119.37674 g mol^-1}$ due to isotopic distribution the mass fraction of carbon is almost exactly the same: $10.06117~\%.$

Yep you are absolutely correct and not missing anything.
If a compound has 10% Carbon by mass then for least molar it should have only one carbon and therefore the least molar mass of compound is 120 g/mol.
The following organic compound satisfies these conditions :


What makes you think you could get a compound like that? It would eliminate HCl even in very low temperatures.

@Mithoron That is a fair point. But the question was from a test that probably wasn't concerned with realism just the principles. And this is, while unrealistic, a creative solution though irrelevant to the question asked!

Yes you are correct. It is that simple(assuming no other information is provided in the question)
(Total Molecular Mass) x (percentage%) = (Molar mass of C)
[10% is 0.1]
(Total Molecular Mass) x 0.1 = 12
Total Molecular Mass = 12/0.1 = 120 g/mol
You can confirm this as well, if you add other atoms to the mix to make a molecule with the carbon mass as 10% of the total molecular mass. I hope this helps.
